# BizTalk 2016 - Debatch XML in XMLReceive pipeline don't Promote Properties

Tags: xsd, biztalk

We have this schema that was working in BizTalk 2009, debatching XML messages in a Receive Port. This schema and the receive location with a XMLReceive pipeline, debatch the messages and generating POLLINGSTMTRECORD messages with OperationType and ProcesoType properties promoted.

But now, in BizTalk 2016 this don't happen, only debatch the messages, but not promote the properties.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:tns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.OracleDB/2007/03/POLLINGSTMTCOMMON" xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" xmlns:ns0="https://ServicesPlatform.Common.Schemas.PropertySchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://Microsoft.LobServices.OracleDB/2007/03/POLLINGSTMTCOMMON" version="1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:annotation>
    <xs:appinfo>
      <fileNameHint xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/servicemodel/adapters/metadata/xsd">POLLINGSTMTCOMMON</fileNameHint>
      <b:schemaInfo is_envelope="yes" xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" />
      <b:imports>
        <b:namespace prefix="ns0" uri="https://ServicesPlatform.Common.Schemas.PropertySchema" location=".\propertyschema.xsd" />
      </b:imports>
    </xs:appinfo>
  </xs:annotation>
  <xs:complexType name="POLLINGSTMTRECORD">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="ID_SOLICITUD" nillable="true">
        <xs:simpleType>
          <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:maxLength value="4000" />
          </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="OPERACION" nillable="true">
        <xs:simpleType>
          <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:maxLength value="40" />
          </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="NUM_REINTENTOS" nillable="true">
        <xs:simpleType>
          <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:maxLength value="4000" />
          </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="PROCESO" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:element name="POLLINGSTMTRECORD" nillable="true" type="tns:POLLINGSTMTRECORD">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:appinfo>
        <b:properties>
          <b:property name="ns0:OperationType" xpath="/*[local-name()='POLLINGSTMTRECORD' and namespace-uri()='http://Microsoft.LobServices.OracleDB/2007/03/POLLINGSTMTCOMMON']/*[local-name()='OPERACION' and namespace-uri()='http://Microsoft.LobServices.OracleDB/2007/03/POLLINGSTMTCOMMON']" />
          <b:property distinguished="true" xpath="/*[local-name()='POLLINGSTMTRECORD' and namespace-uri()='http://Microsoft.LobServices.OracleDB/2007/03/POLLINGSTMTCOMMON']/*[local-name()='ID_SOLICITUD' and namespace-uri()='http://Microsoft.LobServices.OracleDB/2007/03/POLLINGSTMTCOMMON']" />
          <b:property distinguished="true" xpath="/*[local-name()='POLLINGSTMTRECORD' and namespace-uri()='http://Microsoft.LobServices.OracleDB/2007/03/POLLINGSTMTCOMMON']/*[local-name()='NUM_REINTENTOS' and namespace-uri()='http://Microsoft.LobServices.OracleDB/2007/03/POLLINGSTMTCOMMON']" />
          <b:property name="ns0:ProcesoType" xpath="/*[local-name()='POLLINGSTMTRECORD' and namespace-uri()='http://Microsoft.LobServices.OracleDB/2007/03/POLLINGSTMTCOMMON']/*[local-name()='PROCESO' and namespace-uri()='http://Microsoft.LobServices.OracleDB/2007/03/POLLINGSTMTCOMMON']" />
          <b:property distinguished="true" xpath="/*[local-name()='POLLINGSTMTRECORD' and namespace-uri()='http://Microsoft.LobServices.OracleDB/2007/03/POLLINGSTMTCOMMON']/*[local-name()='PROCESO' and namespace-uri()='http://Microsoft.LobServices.OracleDB/2007/03/POLLINGSTMTCOMMON']" />
          <b:property distinguished="true" xpath="/*[local-name()='POLLINGSTMTRECORD' and namespace-uri()='http://Microsoft.LobServices.OracleDB/2007/03/POLLINGSTMTCOMMON']/*[local-name()='OPERACION' and namespace-uri()='http://Microsoft.LobServices.OracleDB/2007/03/POLLINGSTMTCOMMON']" />
        </b:properties>
      </xs:appinfo>
    </xs:annotation>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:complexType name="ArrayOfPOLLINGSTMTRECORD">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="POLLINGSTMTRECORD" type="tns:POLLINGSTMTRECORD" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:element name="ArrayOfPOLLINGSTMTRECORD" nillable="true" type="tns:ArrayOfPOLLINGSTMTRECORD" />
  <xs:element name="POLLINGSTMT">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation>
        <doc:action xmlns:doc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/servicemodel/adapters/metadata/documentation">http://Microsoft.LobServices.OracleDB/2007/03/POLLINGSTMT</doc:action>
      </xs:documentation>
      <xs:appinfo>
        <b:recordInfo body_xpath="/*[local-name()='POLLINGSTMT' and namespace-uri()='http://Microsoft.LobServices.OracleDB/2007/03/POLLINGSTMTCOMMON']/*[local-name()='POLLINGSTMTRECORD' and namespace-uri()='http://Microsoft.LobServices.OracleDB/2007/03/POLLINGSTMTCOMMON']" />
      </xs:appinfo>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="POLLINGSTMTRECORD" nillable="true" type="tns:ArrayOfPOLLINGSTMTRECORD" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

But in BizTalk 2016 is not promoting this properties, any idea?

Comment: Did you upgrade the Project or move the artifacts?

Comment: Also, if you process the debatched message by itself, are the Properties Promoted?

Comment: The problems is that the promoted properties are also distinguished properties. Then with pipeline debatch,these properties aren't promoted. I can see it distinguished but not promoted.

Answer (score 1):

Likely you have the port pipeline set to 'Pass through receive' - promotion is not supported when set to pass through.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/core/default-pipelines

If not, post your property schema as well as your message schema.